# toggleClass works only on td and not whole tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a datatable whch has a checkbox on each row..

When the checkbox will be clicked, the total  will have a class called "selected"

so here is my code which i have put

```
           $("#domains_list").find("input[name=\'chk[]\']").on("click", 
                            function() 
                            {
                                $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");
                            });
```

But the problem is, instead of getting the whole  as class selected, only particular td is getting highlighted.

Here's a screenshot

[image]

so, how can i solve this issue, is there any way?

Comment: could you provide your html?

Comment: Your javascript itself works: http://jsfiddle.net/dqr0bdr2/ So we need to see your CSS and HTML to know what's wrong.

Comment: It is probably css-related rather than the javascript. Make sure the other cells have css rules related to being child of tr.selected, like
`tr.selected * {background:#eee;}`

Answer (score 0):

i have achieved the same purpose by following jQuery code, i hope this will solve your problem as wel.

```
 $(function() {  
  $('td:first-child input').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("selected");
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zougen pointed out, your JS is correct - that is why the td next to the input is being colored and not the td containing the input itself. The other tds wont get highlighted probably because your CSS is being overwritten.

One thing though: your selector looks a little bit strange:

`.find("input[name=\'chk[]\']")` here you dont need to escape the single `'` since your string delimiters are `"` anyways, just write:

```
$('td input[name*="chk"]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("selected");
});
```